# How to resolve a jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have HTML code like below:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Booking Lah</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    .card {
      height: 450px;
    }
    .card-image {
      max-height: 300px;
      max-width: 350px;
      width: auto;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .image-display {
      height: 300px;
      width: auto;
    }
    .helper {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .image-caption {
      height: 100px;
    }
    .star {
      color: orange;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php">Booking Lah</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="register.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">

{{% for row in rows %}}
<div class="col-sm-4 card">
  <div class="image-display">
      <center>
          <span class="helper"></span><img src="{{row['imgurl']}}" class="card-image"><br>
      </center>
  </div>
      <div class="image-caption">
        <center>
          <h1><a href="#">{{row["name"]}}</a></h1>
          <h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star"></span>
          </h2>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
{{% endfor %}}

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and I got an error like this:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
>   TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'
>   File "/home/m26415086/UHTOS/templates/home.html", line 55, in template
>   {{% for row in rows %}}

I'm already trying all I could but nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your template you are using `{{%` and `%}}` instead of `{%` and `%}`.

`{%` is for directives (loops, conditionals, ...) and `{{` for substitution. here is the [doc](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/) for further reference.

Comment: thank you i did not notticed that,but now i have another problem the loop doesent work it wont display any element i put in the loop

Comment: `tmplt = Template(...)` and then `tmplt.render(rows=[{'name': 'first row', 'imgurl': 'first imgurl'}, {'name': 'second row', 'imgurl': 'second imgurl'}])` works fine for me...